# How to capture newly updated information from firebase once

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a project where I need to get data entered on a previous page from firebase, and display it on this page. But, I only want to pull data from on key in the firebase, the newest key.

JS

```
function getData(){
  var ref = firebase.database().ref("Applicant");
  ref.on('child_added', function(snapshot){
    var data = snapshot.val();
    console.log(data);
    var fname = data.fname;
    console.log(fname);
    var mname = data.mname;
    var lname = data.lname;
    var dob = data.dob;
    var gender = data.gender;
    var comeb = data.comeb;
    var hasId = data.hasId;
    var housing = data.housing;
    var kids = data.kids;
    var policy = data.policy;
    var vet = data.vet;
    showData();
```

When I used `on.('child_added')`, it pulls all of the keys from firebase when I only need the one previously entered on the previous page. When I used `on.('value')`, it pulled what I need from firebase, but all of the values where null. I also tried using `.once()` for both `('child_added')` and `('value')`, but they both returned values of null.

Comment: when you save the data to firebase is it redirect to the next page where you want to pull the last added child from firebase. this is how your site works?

Comment: Yes, that is how it is.

Comment: one way is to get the key from callback function when you add to firebase and send it along with redirect.